# How to load a word from an immediate 32 bit address in risc-v assembly?

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32

I want to load a word from 0x0200bff8 address into t1 register.
I tried the following;

```
 lui t0, 0x0200b; // Write Upper 20 bits into t0
 lw t1, 0xff8(t0);  //fetch a word from address in t0 offsetted by 0xff8 (12 bits)
```

I thought its syntactically right, but I see this error

**Error: illegal operands `lw t1,0xff8(t0)'**

What am I doing wrong and what is a good way in terms of less instructions to load a word from an immediate address?

Answer (score 2):

0xff8 is 4088 in decimal.  That value is out of range of the 12-bit signed immediate for `lw` (and all other I-Type instructions).

You could attempt syntax like -8(t0) instead, and, while that will translate into machine code of `lw` with immediate field of `ff8`, it will get the wrong address (0x200aff8) because of sign extension.

However, your `li` solution is much easier to use.  If you look closely at the 2-instruction expansion, you'll see that the `lui` uses `200c` to mitigate the sign extension that happens to the 12-bit immediate on the I-Type instruction.

Also, let's note that your `li` pseudo instruction approach will probably work with `lw` directly (depending on the assembler):

```
lw t0, 0x200bff8
```

However, if that is in a tight loop, it represents 2 instructions, whereas the `li` form can be used to create the address into a register outside of the loop, then in side only a simple `lw` is needed.

For the best of both, optimizing compilers will place just an `lui` outside the loop (instead of the lui/addi pair) and then use the one instruction form of `lw` with rest of the offset.

Comment: Some assemblers allow something like `%hi(0x200bff8)` / `%lo(0x200bff8)` to split for you in a way that works with sign-extended `addi` or `lw` offsets, so you can manually hoist the high half out of a loop and still not waste instructions materializing the low half in a register.  I don't know what GAS for RISC-V uses specifically, but it has this feature for other ISAs like MIPS.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a pseudo instruction `li t0, 0x200bff8;` which does the work.

Comment: That doesn't load from the address, it only puts that constant into a register.  But yes that's the standard way to construct a full constant in a register, which costs you an extra `add` instruction vs. taking advantage of the same immediate width that `lw` supports as offset bits in the addressing mode.